# check whether 'Enter' and 'del' key is pressed in tkinter Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I created n `tk.Entry` in a GUI over a `for` loop using a class. The method `add_input_entries` create the entries and I bonded the update to the `Keypress` event and the update to the `keyrelease` event.

```
def add_input_entries(self): # method of the class creating the entry on a loop
    for item in self.entry:
        item.grid(row=self.row, column=self.__col)
        self.__col += self.__col
        item.bind("<KeyRelease>", self._accept) # update the entry values as the key is released
        item.bind("<KeyPress>", self._validate) # validate the inpur as the key is pressed
```

this is the method for the validation.

```
def _validate(self, event):
    item = event.char
    if item not in ('.', ',') and not item.isnumeric():
        messagebox.showerror(title='Title', message='Invalid character - only numeric characters allowed!!')
        return 'break'
    else:
        if self.nac == 0:
            self.entry_values[1].set(self.entry_values[0].get())
        print(item)
```

now I cannot type any other keys but the ones defined. How can I allow the user to delete the character from the entry and press enter?

Answer (score 1):

A `tk.Entry` widget has a `validate` option which is probably easier to use.

```
import tkinter as tk

def str_is_float( chars ):
    try:
        v = float( chars )
        return chars[-1] != " "
        # This treats '123 ' as invalid even though it coverts to a float.
    except ValueError:
        return len(chars) == 0 or chars in [ "-", ".", "-." ]
        # This allows the strings '-', '.' and '-.' which could start a float.

root = tk.Tk()

validate_cmd = ( root.register( str_is_float ), '%P' )
# '%P' is to pass the new string (after the last keypress ) to the validation.

widget = tk.Entry( root, validate = 'key', validatecommand = validate_cmd )

widget.grid( padx = 10, pady = 10 )

root.mainloop()
```

It's possible to validate the string with other approaches e.g. regex.  I've found allowing an empty string is required to make the entry usable.

tk documentation for [validate](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/entry.html#M13)